# DVD won't load on laptop with Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, drivers, dvd

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my Compaq Presario F700 laptop. When I insert a DVD into the drive, it spins and sounds like it's trying to mount the disk, but nothing opens up. I had Windows Vista on this machine before installing Ubuntu this morning, and it was having the same issue. Is there a driver I need to install? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered the possiblity that the drive or disk might not be working and it isn't an OS problem? Since it isn't working on either ubuntu or windows.

Anyways, for ubuntu, if the disk drive (without the disk in tray) shows a disk drive icon in "computer", or, the disk drive is detected in the program "disks", then there is no problem with drivers.

Comment: Yes, I did consider that possibility, but is there a command I can try to at least make sure the correct drivers are installed?

Comment: i just told you how to check. I know this is linux, but not everything needs commands. There aren't really many ways to get "wrong" drivers per se. If you didn't install "any" drivers, i.e. Everything was automatic, and your drive still shows up in the file manager, then your drivers are correct.

Comment: Got it. Sorry I didn't quite grasp your answer the first time. Thanks for the help!